# Update elements at certain position across list of lists in python efficiently

Tags: python

I want to apply simple function (say, add `1`) to an element at position `0` in each of multiple lists stored within a one list. I so far get here:

```
out = [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]]
print(out)
# [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]]

out_updated = [[out_i[0]+1, out_i[1], out_i[2]] for out_i in out]
out_updated
# [[11, 11, 12], [14, 14, 15], [17, 17, 18], [20, 20, 21]]
```

Is there a nicer (more python-ish, concise) way to obtain `out_updated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using slicing in your comprehension:

```
[[row[0] + 1] + row[1:] for row in out]
```

Could be neater if you make adding `1` to the first element a function:

```
def inc_first_elem(list_):
    return [list_[0]] + list_[1:]

[inc_first_elem(row) for row in out]
```

Incidentally, if you don't mind the additional overhead, numpy arrays are very well suited to this:

```
import numpy as np
out_arr = np.array([[10, 11, 12],
                    [13, 14, 15],
                    [16, 17, 18],
                    [19, 20, 21]])
out_arr[:,0] += 1
```

Comment: Period! I blanked out about `+` to join two lists. Thank you!

Comment: @MartaKaras you can also use `.extend()`